# Teamcity pipe command line output to a file

Tags: windows, command-line, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Is it possible to call a command line program in teamcity and to pipe the output from the command line program to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course - you can use a Powershell build step for this and pipe the console output to a file, here a practical example:

```
git rev-parse HEAD > GitRevision.txt
```

Note that this question/answer is really unrelated to TeamCity - this is just Powershell (you can achieve the same using command line)

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for something similar to : http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Command+Line option .

in 'Build Steps' - you can choose 'Command Line' as Runner Type and in Run select 'Custom script' & write the shell command line to execute in 'Custom script' text area.

```
echo "Hello there!!" | tee someFile.log
```

And add to artifact path if you want to...

Comment: On Windows I had to do `echo "Hello there!!" > "tee someFile.log"`